# submit event is firing without checking validation or showing confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My page is submitting straight away without checking for validation or displaying the alert. I believe the submit is firing early but is my issue that I have multiple forms?

My question is how can I get the submit to work as it should  do where it checks the validation and if that is successful, display the confirmation?

I have had to post my whole code so that you can see the order of the code, because the order of the code maybe my downfall:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#sessionsDrop').change(function () {

            $('#targetdiv').hide();

            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                var split = text.split(' - ');
                $('#currentId').val($(this).find('option:selected').val());
                $('#currentAssessment').val(split[0]);
                $('#currentDate').val(split[1]);
                $('#currentTime').val(split[2]);
            } else {
                $('#currentAssessment,#currentDate,#currentTime,#currentId').val('');
            }
        });

    });


    function validation(e) {

        var isDataValid = true;

        var moduleTextO = document.getElementById("modulesDrop");

        var errModuleMsgO = document.getElementById("moduleAlert");

        if (moduleTextO.value == "") {
            $('#targetdiv').hide();
            $('#assessmentForm').hide();
            $('#choiceForm').hide();
            $('#submitchoicebtn').hide();
            errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select a Module";
            isDataValid = false;
        } else {
            errModuleMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }

        if (isDataValid === false) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation(); //VERY important
            }
            e.returnValue = false;
            e.cancelBubble = true;
        }

        return isDataValid;

    }

    function choicevalidation() {

        var isDataValid = true;

        var currentAssesO = document.getElementById("currentAssessment");

        var currentAssesMsgO = document.getElementById("currentAlert");

        currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";


        if (currentAssesO.value == "") {
            $('#targetdiv').hide();
            currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Select an Assessment to edit from the Assessment Drop Down Menu";
            isDataValid = false;
        } else {
            currentAssesMsgO.innerHTML = "";
        }
        return isDataValid;

    }

    function showConfirm() {

        var examInput = document.getElementById('curentAssessment').value;
        var dateInput = document.getElementById('currentDate').value;
        var timeInput = document.getElementById('currentTime').value;

        if (choicevalidation()) {

            var confirmMsg = confirm("Are you sure you want to take the following Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput + "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);

            if (confirmMsg == true) {
                submitform();
            }
        }
    }

    $('#choiceForm').on('submit', showConfirm);
</script>
 <h1>TAKE AN ASSESSMENT</h1> //FORM 1
<form action="assessmentchoice.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validation(event);">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Module:
                <select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="CHI2513_Systems Strategy_1">CHI2513 - Systems Strategy</option>
                    <option value="CHT2220_Interactive Systems_4">CHT2220 - Interactive Systems</option>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input id="moduleSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Module" name="moduleSubmit"
        />
    </p>
    <div id="moduleAlert"></div>
    <div id="targetdiv"></div>
</form>//FORM 2
<div id='lt-container'>
    <form action='assessmentchoice.php' method='post' id='assessmentForm'>
        <p id='warnings'></p>
        <p><strong>Selected Module:</strong> CHI2513 - Systems Strategy
            <input type='hidden'
            value='1'>
        </p>
        <p><strong>Assessments:</strong> 
            <select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <option value='28'>LDREW - 09-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
                <option value='29'>BQNYF - 10-01-2013 - 10:00</option>
                <option value='22' disabled>WDFRK - 17-01-2013 - 09:00</option>
                <option value='26' disabled>POKUB1 - 25-01-2013 - 15:00</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='rt-container'>//FORM 3 (This is where when submitted it should show confirmation)
    <form
    id='choiceForm' action='assessment.php' method='post'>
        <p><strong>Chosen Assessment:</strong>
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <td>
                    <input type='hidden' id='currentId' name='Idcurrent' readonly='readonly'
                    value='' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Assessment:</th>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly'
                    value='' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Date:</th>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly'
                    value='' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Time:</th>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly'
                    value='' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id='currentAlert'></div>
        <p id='submitchoicebtn'>
            <button id='choiceSubmit'>Choose Assessment</button>
        </p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Code beautified

Comment: Are any Javascript errors returned? If an error occurs, the validation handler will be skipped and the form will be submitted regularly. For example, if jQuery is not included correctly, the `ready` method will not be defined.

Comment: @Boaz There are no javascript errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/48maR/1/)

try to change following line:

```
function showConfirm() { /* your existing code */ }
```

into

```
function showConfirm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* your existing code */

    return false;
}
```

Have you already tried this:

```
function showConfirm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var examInput = document.getElementById('curentAssessment').value;
    var dateInput = document.getElementById('currentDate').value;
    var timeInput = document.getElementById('currentTime').value;

    if (choicevalidation()) {

        return confirm("Are you sure you want to take the following Assessment:" + "\n" + "Exam: " + examInput + "\n" + "Date: " + dateInput + "\n" + "Time: " + timeInput);
    }
    return false;
}

$('#choiceSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
    if (showConfirm(e)) {
        $('#choiceForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer but no luck, still if i click submit button it submits straight away.

Comment: I have tried your update, still submitting though without validation or confirmation. Do I need to change button in html when doing this?

Comment: you have to open your javascript-error-console and see what's also wrong. e.g. change the line document.getElementById('curentAssessment').value; in document.getElementById('currentAssessment').value;

Comment: also move the code  `$('#choiceSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
  if (showConfirm(e)) {
      jQuery('#choiceForm').submit();
  }` inside document ready function

Comment: It did not show anything in error console when there was that error mistake. but it works now thanks to answer and anusha comment on moving it to document ready. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your forms aren't nested so it shouldn't be because there are multiple.

Try removing all of the code in your `validation` function so that it only returns false:

```
function validation(e) {
  return false;
}
```

If this works, you'll know the problem lies within your JavaScript and not the HTML. From there you can add back more and more of the function until you discover which part is causing the issue.

Comment: my validation drop down menu controls the first form, do you still want me to remove content from `validation(e)` or is it `choicevalidation()`? just making sure

Answer (score 0):

i think this line `if ($(this).val() !== '') {` should be like this `if ($(this).val() != '') {`

also as stated in another answers add this: `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I know that line of code worked on another page when testing validation so I don't think that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following code

```
$('#choiceSubmit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = 0;
    if (showConfirm(e)) {
        $('#choiceForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Have you used firebug or inspector (chrome/ie) and stepped through the javascript? In the above case, i'd add a breakpoint at the `e.preventDefault()` method. If it hits this, then the issue is within the javascript. if not then the javascript is not even bound to the submit button.